# Delta function in discontinuous derivative of a wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions, dirac-delta-distributions

In variational principle problem; we need to find $\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}$ to find $\langle T \rangle$; if
\begin{align}
\psi = \begin{cases}
 A \cos ( \pi x / a ) , & -a/2<x<a/2\\
      0        , & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then, how does $\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}$have delta functions at $x= \pm a/2$? This means that $\frac{d\psi}{dx}$ has a Heaviside function; but I can't figure out the Heaviside either.

Quoting from Grifthhs:

> We do not need to worry about the kink at $\pm a/2$. It is true that
> $\frac{d^2 \psi }{dx^2}$ has delta functions there, but since
> $\psi(\pm a/2) = 0$ no “extra” contribution to $\langle T\rangle $
> comes from these points.

Comment: Maybe you can express $\psi$ via a [rectangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function), which admits a representation in terms of Heaviside functions?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "delta functions" that Griffiths is talking about arise from the discontinuity of $\psi'(x)$.  This does not necessarily mean that the definition of $\psi'(x)$ actually has Heaviside step functions in it (though you can think of it as such.)

If we take the derivative of $\psi$ we get
\begin{align}
\psi'(x) = \begin{cases}
 - \frac{\pi A}{a} \sin ( \pi x / a )  & -a/2<x<a/2\\
      0        & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
\end{align}
This is discontinuous at $x = \pm a/2$;  in particular, we have
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left[ \psi'(a/2 + \epsilon) - \psi'(a/2 - \epsilon) \right] = \frac{\pi A}{2}.
$$
But we also have
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left[ \psi'(a/2 + \epsilon) - \psi'(a/2 - \epsilon) \right] = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left[ \int_{a/2 - \epsilon}^{a/2 + \epsilon} \psi''(x) \, dx \right]
$$
and since this integral does not vanish in the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, it must be the case the $\psi''(r)$ (defined as a distribution) includes a delta-function at $x = a/2$.  Similar logic applies to the point $x = - a/2$.

That said, if you really insist on the idea that $\psi'(x)$ must have step functions in it, you can take the approach suggested in the comments and rewrite it as
$$
\psi'(x) = - \frac{\pi A}{a} \sin \left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right) \left[ \Theta\left( x + \frac{a}{2} \right) - \Theta \left( x - \frac{a}{2} \right) \right].
$$
But this sort of rewriting rapidly becomes cumbersome for more complicated functions.  In contrast, the "integral proof" above can be extended straightforwardly to show that any discontinuity in $f^{(n)}(x)$ implies that $f^{(n+1)}(x)$ has a delta function in its distributional derivative.

Answer (score 0):

What Griffith wrote means that if you take the second derivative of the proposed wavefunction, it is
\begin{align}
\psi'' = \begin{cases}
 -A \left( \frac{\pi}{a} \right)^2 \cos ( \pi x / a ) \left( \delta(x+a)-\delta(x-a)\right), & -a/2<x<a/2\\
      0        , & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
However, the contribution of the two deltas to every integral where $\psi''$ is multiplied by a function regular at $\pm a$ is zero due to the vanishing of the cosinus at these two points.